# Merge commands line

Tags: awk, merge

I have these command lines:

```
grep -e "[0-9] ERROR" /home/aa/lab/utb/cic/nova-all.log | awk '{ print $6 }' | awk -F'-' '{print $3""$2""$1}' | cut -c 1-4,7-8 > part1date.txt
grep -e "[0-9] ERROR" /home/aa/lab/utb/cic/nova-all.log | awk '{ print $3" "$4" "$5" "$9 }' > part1rest.txt
grep -e "[0-9] ERROR" /home/aa/lab/utb/cic/nova-all.log | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 15; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s}' > part1end.txt

paste -d \  part1date.txt part1rest.txt part1end.txt  > temp.txt
rm part1*
cat temp.txt
```

The first 3 lines will save its output in a text file.
Then I merged the columns of these texts in one file to show the output.
Can someone help me to use same command in one line without saving them in textfile?

This command used to change the standard output:

```
sep 10 11:13:55 node-20 nova-scheduler 2014-10-12 10:36:55.675 3817 ERROR nova.scheduler....
```

to this format:

```
ddmmyy hh:mm:ss node-xx PROCESS LOGLEVEL MESSAGE
```

that means change place of columns and change the format of the date.

Comment: You can do all of this in a single invocation of awk, although I'd recommend using a script rather than a one-liner. Use `/[0-9] ERROR/` instead of calling grep. Use `split` instead of piping to `awk -F'-'`. If you're already using awk, you don't need to pipe to cut. Make an attempt at combining your lines in an awk script and update your question if you get stuck.

Comment: can you explain to me how im just started with linux and im fresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '/[0-9] ERROR/{gsub("-","",$6);$2=$6;$6=$9;for(i=0;++i<=NF;)$i=i<6?$(i+1):$(i+9);NF-=9;print}' file
```